# The importance of upper critical dimension in spin glass models

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, spin-models

In spin glass models the upper critical dimension is known to be 6, but recently it was [discovered](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.128.075702) to be 8. What is the importance of upper critical dimension for spin glass models? We don't live in 6 dimensions nor 8; what does this physically represent and how can I understand it better?

Comment: Somewhat [related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/442920).

Comment: That was actually helpful! Thanks.