# Why consider more than 3 dimensions in the Ising model?

Tags: spacetime-dimensions, ising-model

Are there real-world physical systems to which higher dimensional ($d>3$) Ising models correspond?

Comment: Well in general you can map a relativistic QFT in $d$-spacetime-dimensions to a statistical field theory/statistical physics problem in $d+1$ dimension.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10527/2451

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we study the Ising model on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ for $d &gt; 3$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/442920/)

Comment: Roger, I think your question has been perfectly answered in the link by @YvanVelenik . If you feel that is not the case, please update your question.

Comment: I do not see a link by YanVelenik. More importantly, I do not see the relation between this question and the supposed duplicate, a part for dealing with dimensions higher than the physical ones.

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90. It was [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/442920/) that I linked to (but my comment disappeared once the question was closed). It is a pretty clear duplicate.